# add custom options to a form

Tags: forms, symfony-2.0

I'd like to pass an option to my form so I did this:

```
            $builder
                ->add('pays', 'collection', array(
                        'type' => new PaysType(),
                        'em' => $this->em,
                        'allow_add' => true,
                )
              );
```

Although I added `em` to my form PaysType I got this error: `he option "em" does not exist`

```
  public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
  {
      $options = parent::getDefaultOptions($options);
      $options['em'] = '';
      return $em;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getDefaultOptions()` should return the options array but you are returning `$em`.  I think that may be your only problem.